# "No instance for" error - but the instance exists (kinds did not match)

Tags: haskell

I get the following error from ghc for my servant library:

```
No instance for (GetEndpoint
                       (Verb 'GET 200 '[JSON] Position)
                       (Verb 'GET 200 '[JSON] Position)
                       'True)
arising from a use of `callServer3'
```

but I have an instance in scope, which looks like that:

```
instance GetEndpoint (Verb n s ct a) (Verb n s ct a) 'True where
  getEndpoint _ _ _ _ server = server
```

which looks exactly like the one ghc can not find. I am a bit confused right now.

Full code can be found here:

- [Instance definition](https://github.com/eskimor/servant-subscriber/blob/2f11e9de5bfc77656aa54918b06da866687638dd/src/Lib.hs) - right at the bottom of the file.
- [File triggering the error](https://github.com/eskimor/servant-subscriber/blob/2f11e9de5bfc77656aa54918b06da866687638dd/test/Spec.hs) - relevant code also at the bottom.

Any clues? Thanks a lot for any hints!

Comment: are you sure that your `kinds` are right (`'GET` vs. `*` etc) (your instance should look like `(Verb (n :: GET) (s :: Nat) ..)` (note I am not sure on the `Nat` here ^^)

Comment: Thanks alot Carsten - that did the trick - I'll post an answer once I resolved the other errors that are now popping up.

Answer (score 5):

The given instance has default kind '*' for n s ct and a. Either use poly kinds as for n or the right concrete kinds:

```
(Verb (n :: k1) (s :: Nat) (ct :: [*]) a)
```

The correct instance would look like this:

```
instance GetEndpoint (Verb (n :: k1) (s :: Nat) (ct :: [*]) a) (Verb n s ct a) 'True where
  getEndpoint _ _ _ _ server = server
```

If you don't want to enable PolyKinds (it introduced a bunch of other errors), you can use the more restricted `StdMethod` for n:

```
instance GetEndpoint (Verb (n :: StdMethod) (s :: Nat) (ct :: [*]) a) (Verb n s ct a) 'True where
  getEndpoint _ _ _ _ server = server
```

Full code (compiling and even working as expected), can be found [here](https://github.com/eskimor/servant-subscriber/blob/cb023f40eda08207d70a96cff567db92630b2448/src/Lib.hs).

Thanks again Carsten for this really quick help!

Comment: PolyKinds will often introduce a lot of errors if suddenly enabled - by default the kind of a type variable defaults to `*` if not specified, but with PolyKinds the kinds of type variables are instead generalized to a fresh kind variable. Also note that you don't need a kind annotation on each occurrence of a type variable - any one is enough.

Comment: Huh - good catch, I am so used to copy pasting with type level programming, that I did not even think about it - but it makes a lot of sense that the annotation is only needed once.